# Primefaces graphicImage always showing the same picture

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, graphicimage

I'm using primeFaces to display the coverimage of a series in it's detailView. My problem is, that it is always showing the same picture, except if I refresh my cache (Strg+F5 in Chrome).

My code to display the picture is the following

```
<ui:define name="content">
    <h:body>
        <f:view>
            <h:form>
                <h1>#{seriesController.selectedSeries.name}</h1>
                <p:graphicImage value="#{coverController.getFirstCoverOfSeries(seriesController.selectedSeries.id)}"/>
                [Here are some fields...]
            </h:form>
        </f:view>
    </h:body>
</ui:define>
```

I already checked my controller manually - it loads the cover just fine, but primeFaces does not display it correctly (Controller returns a DefaultStreamedContent with the byte[] and the correct type).
I've seen some people using `<f:param>` to give the params to the method loading the picture.

I'd really appreciate some help - has `<p:graphicImage>` some quirks or am I just using it wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated in the documentation, by default the `p:graphicImage` is caching, you must add `cache="false"` in order to force a refresh.

**More info**

- [p:graphicImage](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/4.0/primefaces-p/graphicImage.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, I wasn't aware of this. In the showcase they didn't mention it and I didn't look into the docs.